# run a put curl request with basic auth fails

Tags: curl, apache2, owncloud, tls1.3

I am trying to run a curl put request but I get an unhautorized response that I fear is based on my server setup.

The request is the following:

```
curl  -X PUT -v -u 'admin:adminpwd' https://myexampledomain.com/cloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/pinuccio -d 'key=display' -d 'value=ajeje' -H "OCS-APIRequest: true"
```

The response I get is an unhautorized (401). This is the verbose log:

```
*   Trying 127.0.1.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myexampledomain.com (127.0.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=myexampledomain.com
*  start date: May  1 17:18:35 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 30 17:18:35 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "myexampledomain.com" matched cert's "myexampledomain.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> PUT /cloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/pinuccio HTTP/1.1
> Host: mydomain.com
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46QzRsMW0zcjA=
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> OCS-APIRequest: true
> Content-Length: 23
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 23 out of 23 bytes
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2020 14:07:28 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Robots-Tag: none
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
< Set-Cookie: oczw6f5q1725=a8va678tu6ifnku9qqb8ad6g9r; path=/cloud; secure; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: oc_sessionPassphrase=aX2nBbeRkkjX2AOsL9pWoxCcB5vvtdiR4wT9UtOAxfM61oVxCX5LvX02eZkNSfqUPekCdo20A65%2BplZBgHQo%2FyaVQdiQ42d7O4TAqyWpsx8f3gBAeNV%2B2EphYBGNxLmW; path=/cloud; secure; HttpOnly
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; img-src * data: blob:; font-src 'self' data:; media-src *; connect-src *
< Set-Cookie: oczw6f5q1725=0h8mkv831pq6aukvoivr7gf5t2; path=/cloud; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: cookie_test=test; expires=Tue, 30-Jun-2020 15:07:28 GMT; Max-Age=3600
< Set-Cookie: oc_username=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/cloud; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: oc_token=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/cloud; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: oc_remember_login=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/cloud; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: oc_username=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/cloud/; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: oc_token=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/cloud/; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: oc_remember_login=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/cloud/; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: oczw6f5q1725=pi2oc8f3cgut57emv2ikflsooq; path=/cloud; secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: oczw6f5q1725=4hhk94mvb1l6j6re7qi9v68kjo; path=/cloud; secure; HttpOnly
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authorisation Required"
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myexampledomain.com/cloud
< Content-Length: 132
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
< 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
```

I cannot understand from the log where it fails. Can anyone help me to understand? I am running the request directly from the server the api is running on. I also added a CORS allow for mydomain.com/cloud but nothing changed.

On the same API i am able to run a POST request without basic auth. That request runs smootly.
Looks like at some point TLS1.3 fails to keep authenticating...

This is the API documentation: [User Provisioning API - Edit user](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.4/admin_manual/configuration/user/user_provisioning_api.html#edit-user)

Comment: is your password really 'C4l1m3r0' ? why bother with uper case lowercase numbers if its just a permutation of calimero ?

Comment: no, my password is not that one obviously :-)

Comment: your server responds with a 401 , and a WWW-Authenticate: Basic. this usually means you have supplied a wrong username / password combo

Comment: and not usually? these credentials are working fine. I can login with them and I can perform other requests

Comment: it looks like a mis-configured web-server, or bad software, that throws a 401 instead of a 403 (forbidden). of you also need to supply cookies. or something, the cur requests supplies the basic auth. so most certainly its server side. is there an WAF or some kind of load balancer in front of the server?

Comment: no there isn't. The most complex thing is that I have a reverse proxy on /store that resolve to myexampledomain.com:4343 (a node server) but nothing else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216959/discussion-between-on8tom-and-lelio-faieta).

Answer (score 0):

Owncloud 10 API requires TLS1.3 to be enabled.
I was running Apache 2.4.29 (that is the latest version while writing on Ubuntu 18.04 server) that do not support TLS1.3 The first version to support it is 2.4.37

I updated Apache and now everything works as expected. To force the upgrade I had to:

```
//add the repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
//get the updates
sudo apt update
//do the upgrade
sudo apt upgrade
```

Hope this solves someone else headache